# Save elements of Form

Tags: c#, winforms, save

I have made a program were you have a DataGridView with 2 columns. The first column is a read-only textbox (the user can not change it). The second column has the same comboboxes in every row.

[image: the program before opening a file]

If the user changes a combobox, then closes the program, I want the elements to be saved so the next time he opens the program the combobox will be choosen to his selection.

[image: the program after opening a file]

I have managed to save the elements of the first and second column in two text files,example1.txt and example2.txt, but I don't know how to make the saved elements be placed again in the datagridview when the program opens.

Also, the txt files are saved in the path where the csv file is. I want it to be save at the exe path.

Here is what I have made so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string filename = "";
                DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                textBox1.Text = filename;
                string line;
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
             System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text);

            stringforData = file.ReadLine();      
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                fileList.Add(line.Split(';'));
            }

            file.Close();



            this.ToDataGrid();
        }
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    //*************  COLUMN 2 TO STRING[]  ************************************
            string[] colB = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];



            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    colB[i] = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                   File.WriteAllLines("settings2.txt", colB);
                }
        //*************************************************************************
}
     public void ToDataGrid()
        {
            string[] split = stringforData.Split(';');


        foreach (string item in split)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item);
        }
        File.WriteAllLines("settings1.txt", split);
}
```

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of some of the built in goodies of the DataSet object and save your grid data to an XML file and read it back in to the grid when you start the app again.

```
        //note that this will just save it in the bin folder
        //you'll want to use a better path
        string settingsFile = "GridSettings.xml";
        DataTable gridData = null;

        public FormSaveFoo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PrepareSettingsDataSource();
            SetUpDataSourceBindings();

        }

        private void PrepareSettingsDataSource()
        {
            //see if have a settings file
            if (File.Exists(settingsFile))
            {
                //load up the settings 
                DataSet settings = new DataSet();
                settings.ReadXml(settingsFile);
                if (settings.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    gridData = settings.Tables[0];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CreateSettingsTable();
            }
        }

        private void CreateSettingsTable()
        {
            gridData = new DataTable();
            gridData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
            gridData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text"));
        }

        private void SetUpDataSourceBindings()
        {

            dataGridView1.Columns["NameColumn1"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns["TextColumn1"].DataPropertyName = "Text";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = gridData;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //add the grid data to a dataset and then write it to a file
            DataSet persistSettings = new DataSet();
            persistSettings.Tables.Add(gridData);
            persistSettings.WriteXml(settingsFile);
        }
```

Comment: Can not understand what do the    
                                      `dataGridView1.Columns["NameColumn1"].DataPropertyName = "Name";  `


         `dataGridView1.Columns["TextColumn1"].DataPropertyName = "Text";`   
    `gridData = settings.Tables[0];`     


   lines do .....                 
    Please Help!

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns["NameColumn1"].DataPropertyName ="Name"; tells the grid column what datatable column to link to.

gridData = settings.Tables[0]; gets the first table out of the data set read from the XML and assigns it to the data table bound to the grid

Comment: I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You need to change the object names to the ones you are using in your code.

Comment: Whatever you named your columns, you can also just use the column index
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Text"